# How to generate entities from database schema using doctrine-orm-module and zf2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using ["doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.7.0"](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/doctrine-orm-module) with ZF2.

Once I create Entities I usually run following commands to sync and generate database automatically according to my entities.

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create
```

Is there a way to make this process reverse? I mean, Can I generate entities from existing  database in mysql?

Comment: Hi, how to generate Entities in two different db's with ./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create ? Andrea

Answer (score 46, accepted):

We use a batch script:

```
@ECHO OFF

mkdir EXPORT
call .\vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --force --from-database annotation ./EXPORT/
call .\vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:generate-entities ./EXPORT/ --generate-annotations=true

pause
```

`orm:convert-mapping` and `orm:generate-entities` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: The --force option on this saved me another five hours of work. Make sure to use that.

Answer (score 24):

There's a nice blog written on this [here](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/zend-framework-2-generate-doctrine-entities-from-existing-database-using-doctrinemodule-and-doctrineormmodule/)

**Edit:** It can be done by using the commands below: 
 
1. convert-mapping (Table & Entity):

```
  ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Album\\Entity\\" --force  --from-database annotation ./module/Album/src/
```

2. Generates getter and setter

```
   ./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate-entities ./module/Album/src/ --generate-annotations=true
```

Comment: Since this answer relies on a link to another site, and the external site may disappear at a later date, please post all relevant information in your answer.

Comment: @RichardChristensen: You're right! & implemented as well. Can you please upvote. It will be good for me & informative for others as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try just it

```
doctrine orm:convert-mapping -f --from-database annotation entities/

doctrine orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations="true" entities/
```

http://wildlyinaccurate.com/useful-doctrine-2-console-commands/