# doctrine zend zf3 orm entity mapping

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, zend-framework3

Problems generating PHP entites from a database with tables. I am trying to generate entities, getters/setters and any associated annotations from tables already defined in a database.

I have been following several doctrine tutorials but cannot get the entities to successfully generate

Environment (windows xampp PHP 7.1): ZendFramework 3 skeleton application downloaded.

```
"zendframework/zend-component-installer" : "^1.0 || ^0.7 || ^1.0.0-dev@dev",
"zendframework/zend-mvc" : "^3.0.1",
"zfcampus/zf-development-mode" : "^3.0",
"zf-commons/zfc-user" : "^3.0",
"zendframework/zend-log" : "^2.9",
"doctrine/doctrine-orm-module" : "^1.1",
"zendframework/zend-json" : "^3.1"
```

from "App_Root" running the command below generates PHP classes with variable=>field mapping values for each table(note the directory matches namespace structure that is defined):

```
./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace="ModuleName\\Entity\\" --force --from-database annotation ./EXPORT
```

(files generated in /EXPORT/ModuleName/Entity)

So far so good.
Now trying to generate the getters and any additional annotation data using

```
./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate:entities ./EXPORT/ModuleName/Entity
```

Produces:

> [OK] No Metadata Classes to process.

For the life of me I cannot find any configuration with orm:generate:entities that points to some form of Metadata Classes... **Is there a step I'm missing?**

Adjusting the  has no effect.
Please note that to originally get this running I had to adjust the base config to even connect to the database (vendor/doctrine/doctine-orm-module/config/module.config.php) i.e. the script obviously did not pickup any config from the skeleton MVC application.
I've tried installing ZFTool which has it's own issues when running from command line so this was a dead end for me(in zf3 anyway)

So far my options seem to be:

1. Find a way to generate:entities to run via command line with the current tools
2. Find a way to run the ORM tool with context of the ZF3 skeleton app trying to utilise the config
3. Stick with at least the 'annotation' classes generated above and manually add getters/setters and continue... (not what I want to do)
4. Dump doctrine and use /Zend/Db libraries with either TableGateway of customer Select() objects using DBAdapter.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#configuration

https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/zend-framework-2-generate-doctrine-entities-from-existing-database-using-doctrinemodule-and-doctrineormmodule/

[How to generate entities from database schema using doctrine-orm-module and zf2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463291/how-to-generate-entities-from-database-schema-using-doctrine-orm-module-and-zf2)

[creating mapped ORM Entities without the cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903425/creating-mapped-orm-entities-without-the-cli)

Any assistance with a breakdown of steps would be great. Docs and posts online are not effective for me, possibly because I'm missing some simple configuration or directive...

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to run the below command and see if it helps. I have made minor modifications to it.

```
./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate:entities ./EXPORT --generate-annotations=true
```

If the above does not work, you may give this one a try too, just in case.

```
./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:generate:entities ./EXPORT/ModuleName --generate-annotations=true
```

Comment: @JI-Web Can you please comment if this worked for you?